# Minecraft Spigot server error: Block at x, y, z is Block{minecraft:block} but has net.minecraft.world.level.block.entity.TileEntityChest

Tags: minecraft

I own a private SMP server but in the console there are messages spammed that looks like this:
`[21:57:17] [Server thread/ERROR]: Block at -1,151, 69, 777 is Block{minecraft:barrier} but has net.minecraft.world.level.block.entity.TileEntityChest@6a71ab80. Bukkit will attempt to fix this, but there may be additional damage that we cannot recover.`
What is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It means your world is corrupted. Either a rogue admin or a poorly-written plugin messed up your save file.

Comment: How can I fix it? @SilvioMayolo

Comment: Never mind, it was a problem with Spigot. I switched to Paper and this error does not show.